# Django Unit Testing in Visual Studio 2017 or 2019:

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2017, django-unittest, visual-studio-2019

Django needs setup code so unit tests on models that need a database will work. Standard Django unit test do that silently in the background but not with Visual Studio. I have not found a good way to provide setup code that will work for starting test runs from both the Visual Studio Test Explorer and with `django manage.py test`. Visual Studio Test Explorer does not call setUpModule/tearDownModule nor tearDownClass. The following code works from within VS, but I find it ugly, AND it doesn't work with nose/django-nose:

```
import os
import django
import unittest
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment, teardown_test_environment
from django.test.utils import setup_databases, teardown_databases

try:
    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "config.settings.test"
    setup_test_environment()
    print("Called setup_test_environment()")
    django.setup()
    old_config=setup_databases(1,False)
except:
    old_config=None

def tearDownModule():
    try:
        global old_config
        if old_config:
            teardown_test_environment()
            print("Called teardown_test_environment()")
            teardown_databases(old_config,1,False)
    except:
        pass

from unittest import TestCase # This needs to be called after django.setup 
from konsenser.models import Poll   

class PollTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("Setting up class")
        return super().setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("Tearing down class")
        return super().setUpClass()


    def setUp(self):
        Poll.objects.create(name='Test Poll', description='for testing')

    def test_content(self):
        poll=Poll.objects.get(id=1)
        name=f'{poll.name}'
        description=f'{poll.description}'
        self.assertDictEqual({'name':name,'description':description },
                             {'name':'Test Poll','description':'for testing'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When run by VS Test Explorer, the output is

```
Called setup_test_environment()
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Setting up class
```

So it doesn't tear down via my functions/methods. I cannot stick django.setup() into setUpClass because the model import needs django setup already. I wouldn't want to either because I want to create the test database just once and not repeatedly for all test classes.

Anbody any insight? I can't help but thinking I am doing this completely wrong...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Test Explorer For Python Django Tests with Database Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54494257/visual-studio-test-explorer-for-python-django-tests-with-database-access)